Make a simple list using MathJax
I am trying to make a list using MathJax in html. I am trying
\begin{enumerate}
    \item first 
    \item second 
\end{enumerate}

and
\begin{itemize}
    \item first 
    \item second 
\end{itemize}

but my browser is showing Unknown environment 'enumerate' and Unknown environment 'itemize'. I am importing MathJax with
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script> 

Is there a simple way to make a list using MathJax?

MathJax is "A JavaScript display engine for mathematics that works in all browsers."
AFAIK, it does not support LaTeX typesetting that has nothing to do with mathematics.
If you need to render a list in HTML, perhaps using <ul>/<ol> is a better choice.

@MirroMutth the items are math equations, such as 1. a^2 = b^2 + c^2, 2. y = mx + b etc

If they are equation systems or piecewise functions, or something else they are inherently one set, use cases, e.g. g(n) = \begin{cases} f(n), & 0 \leq n \lt 1 \\ f(n-1), & n \geq 1 \end{cases}. If they are just a list of multiple equations, it should be a typesetting issue
